# How to change the links in hundreds of eBay listings (due to website hosting change)?

Tags: template, ebay

One of my client currently runs his store on several platforms.

Despite having his own server, he's been using a different host for the products he's listing on eBay for several years now.
Recently, this host has changed his policy and my client is now willing to host himself the pictures hosted on this external server, for convenience.

Problem is, he has hundreds of products listed on eBay so editing all of them to change the links is going to be quite time-consuming.
So I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this, like mass-downloading the templates, using a find/replace tool and then send back the edited templates.

I have no knowledge on eBay, so I looked around but couldn't find anything related to the mass editing of custom templates.

Comment: Is there not going to be a period of change over when both services will be available? In that case can you not keep the old server until all the old listings expire and any new listings will use the new server?

Comment: Maybe with the API?

Comment: Haven't asked but I presume he's probably using that "relist" option when time's over. Since Christmas is around the corner, the less administrative work he has, the better it is.

The storage will expire end of december so that'll let me time to check other solutions, including the API.

Comment: Can you download the listings with turbo lister which will make a csv that you can find and replace ?

Comment: I looked for TurboLister, it let me search & replace like I wanted :) Thanks!